# extending an irc bot with modules

Tags: python, module, irc

I've created an IRC bot in Python from scratch just for the fun of it. I've got a way to load modules into it, but you have to manually type out the code to load each module as below:

```
if data.find('PRIVMSG %s :add_mod foo\r\n' % channel)
    enabled_mods.append(foo)
if data.find('PRIVMSG %s :rm_mod foo\r\n' % channel)
    enabled_mods.remove(foo)
if data.find('PRIVMSG %s :add_mod bar\r\n' % channel)
    enabled_mods.append(bar)
if data.find('PRIVMSG %s :rm_mod bar\r\n' % channel)
    enabled_mods.remove(bar)
for mod in enabled_mods:
    mod(data,irc,channel,nick)
```

Is there any way to load each module using a for loop for example? Any other suggestions? Such as:

```
modules = [foo,bar]
for module in modules:
    if data.find('PRIVMSG %s :add_mod %s\r\n' % (channel,module))
        enabled_mods.append(module)
    if data.find('PRIVMSG %s :rm_mod %s\r\n' % (channel,module))
        enabled_mods.remove(module)
```

SOLVED.

Comment: "Don't bother answering".  Either delete it or post the answer.  Posting "Don't bother answering" is rude.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the [__import__](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__) function?

Comment: no, aha. I've made a bot that allows extra modules to be added in via type "add_mod [module_name]" into the irc client.